# Foursquare log out button

Tags: php, button, oauth, logout, foursquare

****If interested please see the answer from  Foursquare on this issue as a comment to this post****

Please help, I'm still fighting with this :(

I've created a button that deletes all Foursquare related cookies.
Checked with Firebug, when clicked the cookies are unset.

Also the same programming deletes the token inserted in the database
when the user first logs in. Checked in the database, the row is
deleted.

And here's what happens:

1. In a browser fresh with no cookies, a user logs in.
2. Cookies are set and a row with the token and user id is inserted in
   the database.
3. The user logs out.
4. Cookies unset and row deleted from database
5. Now, a different user wants to log in. He/she clicks     `<a href='".$authorizeUrl."'>Log in</a>`  in my web app.
6. Foursquare login page shows, BUT before he/she can fill the form
   in, the page redirects back to my web app with the previous user token
   and info!

The only way I can do a clean start without point 6 happening is
deleting all cookies from my browser manually :(

Any ideas will be appreciated I don't know where to follow.
Below the code I'm using, please try it you'll see how step 6 happens.

Thanks a ton

```
<?php

ob_start();
require_once('includes/EpiCurl.php');
require_once('includes/EpiSequence.php');
require_once('includes/EpiFoursquare.php');


$logout= $_GET['logout']; 
if ($logout == 'true'){ /*I'm deleting all the cookies foursquare related just in case*/
        $pastdate = mktime(0,0,0,1,1,1970);
               setcookie ("XSESSIONID", "", time() - 18600);
           setcookie ("access_token", "", time() - 18600);
           setcookie ("ext_id", "", time() - 18600);
           setcookie ("LOCATION", "", time() - 18600);
           setcookie("access_token", "", $pastdate);
           setcookie("XSESSIONID", "", $pastdate);
           setcookie("ext_id", "", $pastdate);
           setcookie("LOCATION", "", $pastdate);
           setcookie("_chartbeat2", "", $pastdate);
           setcookie("__utmb", "", $pastdate);
           setcookie("__utmc", "", $pastdate);
           setcookie("__utma", "", $pastdate);
           setcookie("__utmz", "", $pastdate);
           $_SESSION['XSESSIONID']=false;
            unset($_SESSION['XSESSIONID']);


 } 

$clientId = "yyyyyyyyy";
$clientSecret = "xxxxx";
$redirectUrl = 'mypage.php';


   $fsObjUnAuth = new EpiFoursquare($clientId, $clientSecret);

      $thecode = $_GET['code'];

 if(!isset($thecode) && !isset($_COOKIE['access_token'])) { //not in yet

     $authorizeUrl = $fsObjUnAuth->getAuthorizeUrl($redirectUrl); 


    echo"<a href='".$authorizeUrl."'>Let's log in</a>";

 }else{  /*we're in*/



    if(!isset($_COOKIE['access_token'])) {  


         $token = $fsObjUnAuth->getAccessToken($thecode, $redirectUrl);
          setcookie('access_token', $token->access_token);
          $_COOKIE['access_token'] = $token->access_token;     

   }  
        $fsObjUnAuth->setAccessToken($_COOKIE['access_token']);


      echo "we're in";

     echo"<br><a href='mypage.php?logout=true'>Logout</a>";   

 }             

?>
```

Comment: At this time we're not ready to allow third-party applications to log users
out of foursquare.com. If you think users logging out of your application
should be logging out of foursquare.com, we recommend placing a prominent
call to action (e.g. "Log out of foursquare!") on your log-out page.

~ak
--

Comment: I´m having problems with this, i´m working with the Foursquare API, if I login in myapp and then I want to search Fourquare information, but if in the web browser is logged in other user in Fourquare, the result for my search is the information from the active account(not my information), how can I control that?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try changing the value of the expiration date of the cookie before you unset it? It seems that unset does not destroy the cookie.

Comment: I'm doing setcookie("access_token", "", time()-3600); to unset it. Is that wrong? (I'm doing so with the rest of the Foursquare cookies)

Comment: No, that's the correct way. I could be wrong, but maybe you have to see where you are updating the cookie and may have to refresh? if that doesn't affect it, try to see what value that cookie still has using print_r($_COOKIE['access_token']);

Comment: I'm editing the post so I can show you the code I'm using. If you can, please try it. You will see how after clicking logout the cookie is deleted but step 6 happens, and a new login cannot be done (somehow the cookie is set again before the login happens)  :(

Answer (score 1):

You can't really "log out" per se. The token will never expire per Foursquare docs. You are doing everything correct on your end. You need to hit `https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authorize` instead of `https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate`. Hitting `/authorize` will force the user to re-authenticate their identity, (re-log in), and reauthorize your app giving you a new access token to store locally for your app.